# Backbone.js fire event on .remove()

Tags: backbone.js, intervals

I need to fire a function when a Backbone.js view is removed. I guess something like a de-constructor.   The code below is a snippet I wrote; I know it won't work. However, I do remember seeing in the past a video tutorial on how to write a function that does this.  The reason I need to run a de-constructing function is to clear the interval set inside a view when the view is removed.

```
ViewWeather = Backbone.View.extend({
      interval: setInterval(function() {console.log('interval fire');}, 1000),

      // made up function
      deconstructor: function () {
            // if the view is removed
            clearInterval(this.interval);

     }
});

var viewweather = new ViewWeather();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This blog post should give you some better info

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

most notable parts

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){
  this.remove();
  this.unbind();
  if (this.onClose){
    this.onClose();
  }
}
```

and then

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
  },
  render: function(){ ... },

  onClose: function(){
    this.model.unbind("change", this.render);
  }

});
```

Comment: I actually grabed the developmental version of backbone and edited the remove function on a view.  Maybe I should create a fork on github. lol, Now when a view is removed, uninitialize runs for clean up.  So just like you add initialize to your view you can also add uninitialize.  Awesome stuff there bro!
    remove: function() {
      this.$el.remove();
      if (this.uninitialize){
        this.uninitialize();
      }
      return this;
    }

Comment: When you call this.remove() it calls to this.undelegateEvents() automatically? Will it remove the delegate events? (the events in the hash of the class)

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure if I understand you correctly, but the approach you are showing seems correct:

```
dispose: function(id) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.remove();
}
```

you are going to have to call dispose yourself, by e.g. an event:

```
initialize: function(opts) {
    router.bind('route:leave', this.dispose, this); 
},
```

edit after comments: this should work to overload `remove`

```
remove: function() { 
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this); 
}
```

Comment: I am talking about running a function when destroying or removing a view.  This is detecting when the route changes, but thanks for your help.

Comment: you could overload `remove()`